# NPE in Timer.schedule in Spring

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

I have this Service (implements Runnable) autowired in my SpringApplication and it's wired correctly, but `timer.schedule` throws an NPE I can't figure out.

This is my main method:

```
@Autowired
static ExternalDBUpdateThread externalDbUpdateThread;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    logger.info("Server is Strating");
    
    context = SpringApplication.run(SprintChatBotApiApplication.class, args);    
    externalDbUpdateThread = (ExternalDBUpdateThread) context.getBean(ExternalDBUpdateThread.class);
    
    Timer extDbTimer = new Timer();
    extDbTimer.schedule(externalDbUpdateThread, Conf.extDbTimeLoop*60000, Conf.extDbTimeLoop*60000);
    //the line above throws error, extDbTimer!=null && externalDbUpdateThread!=null
}
```

And this is the stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Timer.sched(Timer.java:399)
    at java.util.Timer.schedule(Timer.java:248)
    at pl.sprint.chatbot.SprintChatBotApiApplication.main(SprintChatBotApiApplication.java:62)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: My guess would be that `externalDbUpdateThread` is `null`. That is, `(ExternalDBUpdateThread) context.getBean(ExternalDBUpdateThread.class)` returns `null`.

Comment: No it doesn't, I stated it in my comment. @RogerGustavsson

Comment: Are you sure? Have you used a debugger and checked what values your parameters have when the call is made? A debugger is your friend here.

Comment: @RogerGustavsson I just know it prints `pl.sprint.chatbot.ExternalDBUpdateThread@75fd65c`. How do I test its value?

Comment: What prints `pl.sprint.chatbot.ExternalDBUpdateThread@75fd65c`? Your `logger.info("Server is Strating")` statement? Add a new logger.info(externalDbUpdateThread)` after `context.getBean` but before `extDbTimer.schedule`.

Comment: It's exactly that @RogerGustavsson

Comment: It's exactly what? Was I right in my very first comment?

Comment: No, the  logger.info(externalDbUpdateThread)` after context.getBean but before extDbTimer.schedule prints `pl.sprint.chatbot.ExternalDBUpdateThread@75fd65c` @RogerGustavsson

Comment: I've checked the source code for `java.util.Timer` (around lines 248 and 399), the first parameter to `Timer#schedule(TimerTask, long, long)` being `null` is the only possible reason for this NPE.

Comment: Ok, probably so.. So how would I autowire into a static method (main)? @RogerGustavsson

Comment: I strongly recommend using a `ScheduledExecutorService` instead of `java.util.Timer`.

Comment: @Holger I don't know why, but ScheduledExecutorService has saved my life! If you tell me why I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: I have no idea why it solved your problems. `java.util.Timer` has several drawbacks, so it’s recommended not to use it, but I don’t know whether (or which) one of the drawbacks I know of was responsible for your problem. Perhaps, you solved the issue as a byproduct when rewriting the code to use `ScheduledExecutorService`. I suggest self-answering the question showing the new code.

Comment: Right. But I swear I did nothing more then switching from `timer.schedule()` to `scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate()`.